# Generating matlab regstats interactions model

Tags: matlab, regression

I am doing a multiple regression in MATLAB. I am using regstats with the 'interactions' model type, and I have about 12 predictor variables. My understanding is that 'interactions' will perform the regression with all of the interaction terms. I assume that the order of the new regression variables is a constant, followed by all of the linear terms, followed by all of the interaction terms, but I don't know what order the interaction terms are in.

I know that I can use x2fx with 'interaction' to generate the actual values, but then I have 66 interaction variables, and I can't figure out which is which.

Is there any easy way to figure this out? Is there a way to generate the model that x2fx uses when you select 'interactions'?

Comment: Check out this: http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/x2fx.html It says:  "The interaction terms (pairwise products of the columns of X, in order (1, 2), (1, 3), ..., (1, n), (2, 3), ..., (n–1, n))"

Comment: Thanks. I can't believe I missed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If X has n columns, the order of the columns of D for a full quadratic
>   model is:
>
> 1. The constant term
> 2. The linear terms (the columns of X, in order 1, 2, ..., n)
> 3. The **interaction terms** (pairwise products of the columns of X, **in order (1, 2), (1, 3), ..., (1, n), (2, 3), ..., (n–1, n)**)
> 4. The squared terms (in order 1, 2, ..., n)

[Source](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/x2fx.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the **[anovan](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/anovan.html)** function, which performs the same type of regression if you specify an interaction model and continuous variables. Then, if you called it using three parameters as return values, i.e. [p,table,stats] = anovan(...), you can simply type **stats.coeffnames** and have them neatly displayed. It is also good to note that **stats.coeffs** will display the actual values of the coefficients.